# Update an object that is indirectly related to another object in a list

Tags: apex, soql, controller

I have a list of custom object (Meeting Note) and I want to be able to edit a custom field (Firm Type) from another object (Net Prospect Score) that is indirectly related to the Meeting Note object. They both have a lookup field to Contact object. Below is my attempt at an Apex class that does not work. I was able to only display (in a VF page) the custom field but it does not update.

```
public class MeetingNoteCtrlr{

public List<MeetingNote__c> meetingNotesOutstanding {get; set;}
public MeetingNoteMDHomePageCtrlr() {

    meetingNotesOutstanding = [
        SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD), Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__r.Firm_Type__c
        FROM MeetingNote__c
        LIMIT 100];
}

public PageReference saveMeetingNotes() {

    try{
       update meetingNotesOutstanding;
    }
    catch(DmlException ex){
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Simply make sure you pull out a set of the unique `Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__c` IDs and use these to construct the `Net_Prospect_Score__c` records to update. DML only applies to the records you explicitly pass to the `update` (and other) operation; it does not apply to related objects (so writing to `Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__r.Firm_Type__c` will not get saved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DML** operations will **not** update **Child** records in the records whihc you pass to it,

So you need to create another list for `Net_Prospect_Score__c` object and update this list.
Also you need to add another parameter to your query to get `Net_Prospect_Score__c` Id.

The **updated code** will look like this :

```
public class MeetingNoteCtrlr {
    public List<MeetingNote__c> meetingNotesOutstanding {get; set;}
 
    public MeetingNoteMDHomePageCtrlr() {
        meetingNotesOutstanding = [
              SELECT FIELDS(STANDARD),
              Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__c
              Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__r.Firm_Type__c
              FROM MeetingNote__c
              LIMIT 100];
    }
 
    public PageReference saveMeetingNotes() {
        try{
            List<Net_Prospect_Score__c> netProspectScores = new List<Net_Prospect_Score__c>();
            for(MeetingNote__c meetingNote: meetingNotesOutstanding) {
                if( 
                    meetingNote.Name__c != null 
                    && meetingNote.Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__c != null 
                ){
                    netProspectScores.add( 
                        new Net_Prospect_Score__c( 
                            Id = meetingNote.Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__c, 
                            Firm_Type__c = meetingNote.Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__r.Firm_Type__c 
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
            update netProspectScores;
        } catch(DmlException ex){
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }      
}
```

Some of Object or fields **API Names** may be **different**,
So if you **copy-paste** the code than you should check it.

**--- Update ----**

If multiple Contacts can be related to the same net prospect score,
You **need** to make sure that there are no duplicates in **netProspectScores** list.
You can use a **Map** instead of a **list** or make sure there are no
`Net_Prospect_Score__c` duplicates returned in the query.

The variant with Map will look like this :

```
****
    Map<Id,Net_Prospect_Score__c> netProspectScoresMap = new Map<Id,Net_Prospect_Score__c>();
    for(MeetingNote__c meetingNote: meetingNotesOutstanding) {
        if( 
           meetingNote.Name__c != null 
           && meetingNote.Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__c != null 
        ){
            netProspectScoresMap.put( 
                meetingNote.Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__c,
                new Net_Prospect_Score__c( 
                    Id = meetingNote.Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__c, 
                    Firm_Type__c = meetingNote.Name__r.Net_Prospect_Score__r.Firm_Type__c 
                )
            );
        }
    }
    update netProspectScoresMap.values(); 
***
```

**Ensure** you do not lose any data with the Map approach, as if there are **multiple Contacts with the same net prospect score** you can **lose** some data.

Comment: This code is likely to fail if multiple Contacts can be related to the same net prospect score which I why I said you need a set of the unique IDs in my comment.

Comment: I also believe the Lookup field will automatically be populated without explicit listing in the SOQL because field(s) in these referenced objects are being loaded.

Comment: @PhilW thanks, I agree with you. I have updated my answer.